# Send emails to nextApproverIds and prevent sending to Actor

Tags: approval-process

Is it possible to send emails only to NextApproverIds and not to Actor already set in Approval process.I tried dynamically instantiating an approval process and I set actor as the manager of the submitter but I dont want him to receive any email nor he should be able to approve or reject any record? or any alternative solution

Comment: It's really urgent. .any sort of help please?